# Spring Boot - JPA query execution Time

Tags: java, comparative-review, spring-mvc, jpa

Any one suggest me right way to write mapping more then one table using spring-boot (jpa), i was done it, but its required more time to extract result,

Following are the Mapping of Pojo:

First:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DIM_CORPORATE_AND_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING")
public class ServiceAttributeMapping {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="N_CORPORATE_SERVICE_MAP_SKEY")
    private long serviceMapSkey;

    @Column(name="V_MAP_WITH")
    private String mapWith;

    @Column(name="F_LINKED_WITH_MAIN_SERVICE")
    private String fLikedWithMainService;

    @Column(name="V_STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Column(name="N_DIM_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_SKEY")
    private Long attOptionSkey;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "N_DIM_CORPORATE_SKEY", referencedColumnName = "N_DIM_CORPORATE_SKEY")
    private CorporateServicesDetails corporateSericeDetails;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "N_DIM_ATTRIBUTE_SKEY", referencedColumnName = "N_DIM_ATTRIBUTE_SKEY")
    private ServiceAttribute serviceAttribute;
}
```

Second Mapping :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DIM_CORPORATE_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE")
public class ServiceAttribute {

    @Id
    @Column(name="N_DIM_ATTRIBUTE_SKEY")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long attributeSkey;

    @Column(name="V_ATTRIBUTE_NAME")
    private String attributeName;

    @Column(name="F_FINAL_ELEMENT")
    private String fFinalElement;

    @Column(name="V_STATUS")
    private Integer status;

     @JsonIgnore
     @OneToOne(mappedBy="serviceAttribute")
     private ServiceAttributeMapping AttributeMapping;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="serviceAttribute")
     private Set<ServiceAttributeOptions> serviceAttributeOptions;

     @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "N_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "N_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_ID")
     private AttributeType attributeType;

}
```

Third Pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DIM_CORPORATE_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_OPTIONS")
public class ServiceAttributeOptions {

    @Id
    @Column(name="N_DIM_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_SKEY")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long optionSkey;


    @Column(name="N_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_ID")
    private long attributeTypeId;

    @Column(name="V_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_NAME")
    private String optionName;


    @Column(name="F_FINAL_ELEMENT")
    private String finalElement;

    @Column(name="V_STATUS")
    private String status;


    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "N_DIM_ATTRIBUTE_SKEY")
    private ServiceAttribute serviceAttribute;
}
```

Query :-

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
        List<CorporateServicesDetails> corporateServiceslist = entityManager.createQuery(
                "select r from ServiceAttributeMapping r INNER JOIN r.serviceAttribute i where r.mapWith=:mapWith and r.fLikedWithMainService='Y' and r.status='1' ")
                .setParameter("mapWith", "MAIN").getResultList();
        return corporateServiceslist;
```

Thanks in advance